# Connect to Teradata Database using R + DBI library + ODBC

Tags: r, windows, odbc, teradata, r-dbi

I'm trying to connect to a Teradata Database in R using the DBI library (if it matters I'm on Windows). I can successfully connect using the RODBC library so I know my credentials etc. are correct.

I suspect the issue is:

- I am not correctly specifying the authentication mechanism
- Wrong driver: instead of using ODBC, perhaps I should be using JDBC?

---

Background:

First here's my ODBC info if I look it the ODBC Database Source Administrator:

- Name = name_name
- Driver = Teradata
- Name or IP address = address.here.ok
- Mechanism = ldap
- Username = my_username

[image: Screenshot of "ODBC Driver Setup for Teradata Database" window]

Using R 3.5.1 (2018-07-02), RStudio, Windows 10.

---

What works:

```
library(RODBC) 
con = odbcConnect(dsn = "name_name"
                  ,uid = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Username")
                  ,pwd = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Password")
                  )
```

---

What I've tried with DBI and fails:

```
library(DBI)

con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc()
                      ,driver = "Teradata"
                      ,DBCName = "name_name"
                      ,host   = "address.here.ok"
                      ,uid    = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database user")
                      ,pwd    = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database password"))
```

Error: `Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:950: 28000: [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database] The UserID, Password or Account is Invalid`

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc()
                      ,driver = "Teradata"
                      ,DBCName = "name_name"
                      ,host   = "address.here.ok"
                      ,uid    = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database user")
                      ,pwd    = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database password")
                      ,MechanismName = "ldap")
```

Error: `Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:950: 28000: [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database] The UserID, Password or Account is Invalid`

I've seen this error in similar situations when the mechanism is not specified correctly (`ldap`), so maybe `MechanismName` is wrong?

I know I can say whatever I like in the connection string and no error is raised so if `MechanismName` is not the correct way to specify the authentication mechanism I will not have an error returned. For example:

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc()
                      ,driver = "Teradata"
                      ,DBCName = "name_name"
                      ,host   = "address.here.ok"
                      ,uid    = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database user")
                      ,pwd    = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database password")
                      ,MechanismName = "ldap")
                      ,made_up_input = "I like cats"
```

gives the error: `Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:950: 28000: [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database] The UserID, Password or Account is Invalid`

Thanks in advance.

Edit: got idea to use `MechanismName` [from an issue raised in Git](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/92)

Comment: Like R, DBI is C-based and speaks ODBC. If it were Java-based, it would speak JDBC. I suggest you test with hard-coded UID and PWD, before using the `askForPassword` function. That said, I believe you may succeed with `DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc() ,dsn = "name_name" ,uid = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Username") ,pwd = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Password") )`.

Comment: Thanks @TallTed for the explanation as well as solution. Your suggestion worked :). If you want to put it as an answer I'll vote on it, otherwise I'll write up your solution and credit you for it. Cheers! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like R, DBI is C-based and speaks ODBC. If it were Java-based, it would speak JDBC.

I would suggest you test with hard-coded UID and PWD, before using the `askForPassword` function.

That said, I believe you will succeed with --

```
DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc() 
    ,dsn = "name_name" 
    ,uid = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Username") 
    ,pwd = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Password")
   )
```

Comment: Actually the main issue of OP is using a DSN vs. Driver, two ODBC methods. DSNs are prepared in advance with all driver and other connection details, avoiding the need to write out in application layer. Drivers must include all needed connection details in app layer.

Comment: Yes and no, @Parfait. A preconfigured DSN does contain all the attributes necessary for the connection -- including the `driver=` attribute. The OP did not know that `DBI` would accept the same simple ODBC connect string (i.e., using `dsn=`) as `RODBC`, and so was trying to create the complete ODBC connect string (`driver=...;attr1=...;attr2=...;uid=...;pwd=...;etc.`) which is automatically built by the ODBC libraries when using the `dsn=...;uid=...;pwd=...` string.

Comment: Your response I believe echoes mine that there are two methods to connect with ODBC whether using RODBC or DBI (even beyond R): 1) driver or 2) DSN. Agreed. The main issue was OP was unaware of DSN version in DBI. The failed DSN-less driver attempts indicate OP did not satisfy all attributes the DSN carries. I commented because your opener emphasized JDBC which is a tangential question by OP and not related to OP's attempts. In fact, your above comment should be in body of your answer for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

For those finding this late, the original DBI call will only work if the exact name of the driver as it appears in your ODBC manager is provided. Open the ODBC Data Source Administrator app and click on the Drivers tab. Enter the driver name exactly as it appears in the Name column and it should work. Example, 'Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.10' instead of 'Teradata' as shown above.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).