# How to connect to Teradata Database using R + DBI +ODBC with osx (and windows VM)

Tags: r, odbc, teradata, r-dbi

I work on a Mac, but also have a windows VM.

I am trying to connect to a Teradata Database on both my Mac and Windows VM using R with the DBI library (so I can use dbplyr). Everything is working great on my Windows VM (see my previous question: [Connect to Teradata Database using R + DBI library + ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54337267/connect-to-teradata-database-using-r-dbi-library-odbc)).

Again I suspect a driver issue, but I am not sure. I'm sure I had this working last week, but I can't remember. I know I have updated my Mac.

---

Background:
First here's my ODBC info if I look it the ODBC Administrator:

- Name = name_name
- Driver = Teradata
- Name or IP address = address.here.ok
- Mechanism = ldap
- Username = my_username

See an screenshot of my ODBC administrator 
[image: ODBC administrator] 
and the drivers
[image: the drivers]

I downloaded the ODBC driver for Mac from [Teradata](https://downloads.teradata.com)

I use R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02) and the teradata driver 16.20.

---

What works (on Mac and Windows):
library(RODBC)

```
con = odbcConnect(dsn = "name_name"
                  ,uid = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Username")
                  ,pwd = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Password")
                  )
```

---

What doesn't work on Mac (but works on Windows)

```
con = DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc()
                  ,dsn = "name_name"
                  ,uid = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Username")
                  ,pwd = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Password")
                  )
```

On Mac I get the error `Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:950: IM002: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified`.

I have also tried other values in my connection string with no luck as described [here](https://db.rstudio.com/databases/teradata/), e.g:

```
con = DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc()
                  ,Driver = "Teradata"
                  ,Host = "address.here.ok"
                  ,DBName = "name_name"
                  ,uid = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Username")
                  ,pwd = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Password")
                  )
```

Thankyou in advance.

**Edit: update**

Based on suggestions from @TallTed I checked the two locations where DBI will “look” for the odbc file.

- `/usr/local/etc/` directory has files `odbc.ini` and `odbcinst.ini` but they’re completely empty
- `/etc/` had neither `odbc.ini`  or `odbcinst.ini`

I also looked in the locations @TallTed suggested the DBI library would look:

- `/Users/*/Library/ODBC` has both `odbc.ini` and `odbcinst.ini`.  `odbc.ini` is filled in with information and `odbcinst.ini` doesn't have much.
- `/Library/ODBC/` only has `odbcinst.ini` which is filled with information and an empty folder called `ODBCDataSources` (not sure if there are hidden files in there).
- `/Users/*/.odbc.ini` exists with nothing in it, I couldn’t open `/Users/*/.odbcinst.ini`

So far, in `/usr/local/etc/` I removed `odbcinst.ini` and `odbc.ini` and crated the following symlinks:

- (link to odbc.ini file)`ln -s /Users/*/Library/ODBC/odbc.ini /usr/local/etc`
- (link to odbcinst.ini file)`ln -s /Library/ODBC/odbcinst.ini /usr/local/etc`
- (link to ODBCDataSources folder) `ln -s /Library/ODBC/ODBCDataSources /usr/local/etc`

I couldn't create symlinks into `/etc/` folder for example I got the error:

- `ln: /etc/odbc.ini: Permission denied`

Now I get `Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:950: HY000: [Teradata][ODBC] (11560) Unable to locate SQLGetPrivateProfileString function.`

**Edit 2: solution**

```
con = DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc()
               ,driver = "/Library/Application Support/teradata/client/16.20/lib/tdataodbc_sbu.dylib"
               ,DBCName = "address.goes.here"
               ,MechanismName = "ldap"
               ,uid = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Username")
               ,pwd = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Password"))
```

The path `/Library/Application Support/teradata/client/16.20/lib/tdataodbc_sbu.dylib` is just from ODBC Administrator > Drivers tab

Comment: Note that when you get error `Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:950: HY000: [Teradata][ODBC] (11560) Unable to locate SQLGetPrivateProfileString function.` then "the name of the library file for the driver manager is different from the default".
Please see [Teradata - Specifying ODBC Driver Managers's](https://www.simba.com/products/Teradata/doc/ODBC_InstallGuide/linux/content/odbc/configuring/librarypath.htm) "Troubleshooting" section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ODBC Administrator you're running is working with the iODBC Driver Manager (which Apple ships with macOS).  iODBC looks to specific default locations for the ODBC configurations --

```
/Library/ODBC/odbc.ini
/Library/ODBC/odbcinst.ini
/Users/*/Library/ODBC/odbc.ini
/Users/*/Library/ODBC/odbcinst.ini
/Users/*/.odbc.ini -> /Users/*/Library/ODBC/odbc.ini
/Users/*/.odbcinst.ini -> /Users/*/Library/ODBC/odbcinst.ini
```

Based on the success and failure you report, RODBC is apparently built against iODBC, but DBI is apparently built against the unixODBC Driver Manager, which looks to different default locations --

```
/etc/odbc.ini
/etc/odbcinst.ini
/usr/local/etc/odbc.ini
/usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini
```

You may find success by using the *full* `[name_name]` DSN definition as found in the relevant `odbc.ini` file to construct a DSN-less ODBC connect string for your `DBI::dbConnect()` call.

Alternatively, you might move (most of) the content of the latter files into the former files, and replace the latter files with symlinks to the others, such that both Driver Managers use the same configuration files -- even though some apps and some drivers will only work with one Driver Manager.

Comment: Thanks again @TallTed I'll give this a go now. I really appreciate all you've shared with me :)

Comment: @i_love_chocolate - Note that I've updated my answer a bit. The basic advice remains the same, but some details about RODBC and DBI have changed.

Comment: Thanks I gave the symlink suggestion a go and haven't had much luck - I could only copy to `/usr/local/etc/` I copied the files which had the most information. I posted what I did above.

Comment: What would a DSN-less ODBC connect string look like? I tried putting in the path to the .ini file and also this: `con2 = DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), dsn = "/Library/Application Support/teradata/client/16.10/lib/tdata.dylib", uid = "username", pwd = "password")` and got `Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:950: IM012: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]DRIVER keyword syntax error`

I'm beyond what I know here so I'm not sure how to execute each step to fix the issue.

Comment: Also FYI just found this which sounds like a similar problem to what I'm having: https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/16

Comment: fixed it just now, I was pointing to the wrong library, will post what I did in second edit. AWESOME! Thanks heaps! :)

Comment: `/etc` is a special privileged directory; you need to use `sudo` to make changes there. Note that I did not suggest simply adding symlinks there, but replacing existing files with symlinks; these are different actions. Note that a symlink to `/Users/*/Library/` is problematic as that `*` is a wildcard and that link thus may expand to multiple files, which these libraries won't know how to handle. I probably should have used `~` instead of `/Users/*` (e.g., `~/.odbc.ini`, `~/Library/ODBC/odbc.ini`). `~/.odbc.ini` should not exist unless it is a symlink to `~/Library/ODBC/odbc.ini`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, much appreciated!